# Removing mirrored combinations of variables in a data frame

Tags: r, purrr

I'm looking to get each unique combination of two variables:

```
library(purrr)
cross_df(list(id1 = seq_len(3), id2 = seq_len(3)), .filter = `==`)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
    id1   id2
  <int> <int>
1     2     1
2     3     1
3     1     2
4     3     2
5     1     3
6     2     3
```

How do I remove out the mirrored combinations? That is, I want only one of rows 1 and 3 in the data frame above, only one of rows 2 and 5, and only one of rows 4 and 6. My desired output would be something like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    id1   id2
  <int> <int>
1     2     1
2     3     1
3     3     2
```

I don't care if a particular `id` value is in `id1` or `id2`, so the below is just as acceptable as the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    id1   id2
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     2     3
```

Comment: Just figured it out: `df %>% mutate(sum = id1 + id2) %>% 
  distinct(sum, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-sum)` should do it.

Comment: I'm concerned that if you have two rows with the same sum but different digits, e.g., (2,4) and (1,5), that you will only keep one of them.  See my proposed solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Base R approach:

```
# create a string with the sorted elements of the row
df$temp <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))

# then you can simply keep rows with a unique sorted-string value
df[!duplicated(df$temp), 1:2]
```

Comment: Hi Dan, good point in your comment above. Thanks for this. I've also worked a tidyverse solution that does something similar as your answer. I'll post it separately.

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse version of Dan's answer:

```
cross_df(list(id1 = seq_len(3), id2 = seq_len(3)), .filter = `==`) %>% 
  mutate(min = pmap_int(., min), max = pmap_int(., max)) %>% # Find the min and max in each row
  unite(check, c(min, max), remove = FALSE) %>% # Combine them in a "check" variable
  distinct(check, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% # Remove duplicates of the "check" variable
  select(id1, id2)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    id1   id2
  <int> <int>
1     2     1
2     3     1
3     3     2
```